# How to create an auto delete video

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me how to create an auto delete/self destruction video in PC/Pen drive?

I'm doing a project and its very important to keep my data confidential... Could you please help me?

Comment: As in [Mission Impossible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0tNw4jNp28)?

Comment: The 'otp' package creates a single-use-only decryption-key.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Disclaimer: This is merely a fun and play approach and not at all a secure way to keep others from viewing or obtaining files.</sub>

A simple but of course not really secure way would be to hide and encrypt the video and write a script which decrypts, plays and then immediately removes the video file and itself. I use `ccrypt` and VLC here, both need to be installed on the target system.

#### Preparation

Copy the video over, I use `.secret` as the hidden filename and `/target/path/` as the target path:

```
cp /path/to/video /target/path/.secret
```

Encrypt it with a password, “1234” seems to be commonly used so it must be secure:

```
ccrypt -eK 1234 /target/path/.secret
```

Save the following script as e.g. `/target/path/play_video`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
f="${0%/*}/.secret"
pw="1234"
ccrypt -dK "$pw" "$f".cpt
vlc --playlist-autostart --play-and-exit -f "$f"
rm "$f" "$0"
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x /target/path/play_video
```

#### Usage

In `/target/path/` by default you now only see the script, only if you list hidden files as well you see the video file, but it is encrypted with an unknown password and can’t be played directly. Hopefully the target user runs the script, which decrypts the file, plays it with VLC in fullscreen mode and deletes both files directly after the video ends.

If they’re smart though, they’ll have a look at the script, get the password from it and work around this easily. You could use a binary file to hide the password, but the video is still getting decrypted before playing it, leaving it accessible while the player is open.